# How to match a specific string as a capturing group with unspecified position

Tags: regex

I have a text file with a cli output and I need to get certain info from every record, however the file is poorly formatted. I have the regex and the data at:

https://regex101.com/r/1T3icV/2

I am unable to get the value(file/none) of guarantee in a capturing group.
Any help is greatly appreciated

*EDIT*

I need to get the Volume, state, Raid, Flex, root(if available) and the value of the "guarantee" field(guarantee=XXX, I need only the XXX) in separate capturing groups, in a **single match**. rest of the data is not really useful to my usecase.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to get.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I do not know the language actually, I am working on an already built platform and I am just changing the configurations. however, the syntax seems to be either python or PCRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex I used is:

```
(?=(?P<volume>\w+) (?P<state>o(?:n|ff)line)|(?P<options>(?:(?:root|\w+=\w+))+)|(?P<status>(?:(?:raid(?:_dp|4)|flex|cluster|64-bit))))[\w=]+
```

This uses placeholders to allow easily identifiable grouping (if any of these are in the wrong place then let me know, basically).

Using a positive lookahead, will grab the volume and state, then looks for options, and finally handles status. It seems the status types are pretty well defined, at least in this data.

Here's the python I used to get the output that I believe you want:

```
import re

regex = r"(?=(?P<volume>\w+) (?P<state>o(?:n|ff)line)|(?P<options>(?:(?:root|\w+=\w+))+)|(?P<status>(?:(?:raid(?:_dp|4)|flex|cluster|64-bit))))[\w=]+"
test_str = ("2 entries were acted on.\n\n"
            "Node: abc-01\n"
            "         Volume State           Status                Options\n"
            "           vol0 online          raid_dp, flex         root, guarantee=file, nvfail=on, space_slo=none\n"
            "                                64-bit\n\n"
            "Node: abc-02\n"
            "         Volume State           Status                Options\n"
            "           vol0 online          raid_dp, flex         root, nvfail=on, space_slo=none, guarantee=none\n"
            "                                64-bit\n"
            " asdfbw017_5_vol online          raid4, flex           nvfail=on, create_ucode=on, convert_ucode=on,\n"
            "                                cluster               schedsnapname=create_time, fractional_reserve=0,\n"
            "                                64-bit                space_slo=none\n"
            " asdfbw018_2_vol online          raid4, flex           nvfail=on, create_ucode=on, convert_ucode=on,\n"
            "                                cluster               schedsnapname=create_time, fractional_reserve=0,\n"
            "                                64-bit                space_slo=none, guarantee=none\n"
            "werwr_1_WINDOWS_1 online          raid4, flex           nvfail=on, create_ucode=on, convert_ucode=on,\n"
            "                                cluster               schedsnapname=create_time, fractional_reserve=0,\n"
            "                                64-bit                space_slo=none\n"
            "werwr_2_RHEL_2_vol online          raid4, flex           nvfail=on, create_ucode=on, convert_ucode=on,\n"
            "                                cluster               schedsnapname=create_time, fractional_reserve=0,\n"
            "                                64-bit                space_slo=none\n"
            "werwr_2_RHEL_1_vol online          raid4, flex           nvfail=on, create_ucode=on, convert_ucode=on,\n"
            "                                cluster               schedsnapname=create_time, fractional_reserve=0,\n"
            "                                64-bit                space_slo=none, guarantee=none\n"
            "werwr_1_WINDOWS_2 online          raid4, flex           nvfail=on, create_ucode=on, convert_ucode=on,\n"
            "                                cluster               schedsnapname=create_time, fractional_reserve=0,\n"
            "                                64-bit                space_slo=none\n"
            "  werwr_1_ESX_2 online          raid4, flex           nvfail=on, create_ucode=on, convert_ucode=on,\n"
            "                                cluster               schedsnapname=create_time, fractional_reserve=0,\n"
            "                                64-bit                space_slo=none\n"
            " asdfbw018_1_vol online          raid4, flex           nvfail=on, create_ucode=on, convert_ucode=on,\n"
            "                                cluster               schedsnapname=create_time, fractional_reserve=0,\n"
            "                                64-bit                space_slo=none\n"
            "  werwr_1_ESX_4 online          raid4, flex           nvfail=on, create_ucode=on, convert_ucode=on,\n"
            "                                cluster               schedsnapname=create_time, fractional_reserve=0,\n"
            "                                64-bit                space_slo=none\n"
            "werwr_1_W2K8_01 online          raid4, flex           nvfail=on, create_ucode=on, convert_ucode=on,\n"
            "                                cluster               schedsnapname=create_time, fractional_reserve=0,\n"
            "                                64-bit                space_slo=none\n"
            " asdfbw017_2_vol online          raid4, flex           nvfail=on, create_ucode=on, convert_ucode=on,\n"
            "                                cluster               schedsnapname=create_time, fractional_reserve=0,\n"
            "                                64-bit                space_slo=none")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

allData = {}
currentVolume = ""

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1
    volume = match.groupdict()['volume']
    state = match.groupdict()['state']
    options = match.groupdict()['options']
    status = match.groupdict()['status']

    if volume is not None:
        currentVolume = volume
        allData[volume] = {'state': [], 'options': [], 'status': []}
    if status is not None:
        allData[currentVolume]['status'].append(status)
    if state is not None:
        allData[currentVolume]['state'].append(state)
    if options is not None:
        allData[currentVolume]['options'].append(options)

print(allData)
```

Sample Output of one volume:

```
{'werwr_1_ESX_2': {'options': ['nvfail=on', 'create_ucode=on', 'convert_ucode=on', 'schedsnapname=create_time', 'fractional_reserve=0', 'space_slo=none'], 'status': ['raid4', 'flex', 'cluster', '64-bit'], 'state': ['online']}
```

Check it out [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Hyb-XDk8M)

**Edit**

After the question was edited, I managed to get the information with this:

```
(?P<volume>\w+)\s+(?P<state>o(?:n|ff)line)\s+(?:(?P<raid>raid\w+),\s+)?(?P<flex>flex)?(?:.*?(?:(?P<root>root)|guarantee=(?P<guarantee>\w+)))*
```

Check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/1T3icV/3)

It still uses grouping (especially for the root|guarantee section) as not to assume the order of these, but should now do what you want in a single match.

Comment: I have edited the question to better reflect my problem. but man, that was an amazing use of regex. I didn't even know that was possible. thanks for the effort.

Comment: @AntarikshaYelkawar I've updated the answer with a new regex that should do that.

Use the first to grab everything should you wish, but the second will grab just what you've asked for.

Comment: this works well but only if the guarantee was in the first line, however this ignores all other lines. there are few records with guarantee in the second and third lines but these are ignored.